# Set before ERA dates in ICU4J in JAVA

Tags: java, date, calendar, icu

I'm using `ICU4J` calendar library for converting dates between calendar systems (Gregorian, Japanese, Chinese, Jalali, Islamic,...).
I use it with normal dates (after ERA) like this :

```
Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(dateOBJ);
```

Is it possible to set before ERA dates (e.g. year 500 BC)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has its implementation, I used this:

```
calObj = new GregorianCalendar(500,6,12,0,0,0);
calObj.set(GregorianCalendar.ERA, GregorianCalendar.BC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Try

```
gc.setTime(new Date((long)((-500-1970)*(86400.0)*(365.25)*(1000.0))));  // -17104219200.00, approx 500BC
```

Comment: just a small formatting change. nothing of any consequence.  :-)